# Which Crystal Reports Runtime version to use for 13.0.4000.0 - Windows C# app

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a Visual Studio 2010 C# Windows app that uses Crystal Reports.

I have installed Crystal Reports 13.0.29.3671 on my development PC and can build/run the application. I can display the reports at runtime/design time without any problems.

The Visual Studio application references: -

1. CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
2. CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
3. CrystalDecisions.Shared
4. CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

All which say version 13.0.4000.0

Which Crystal Reports Runtime version do I need to use on the client PC?

I installed the "CR for Visual Studio SP29 CR Runtime 32-bit MSI" on the client PC but when I try and display a report via the application I get this error: -

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils threw an exception. --->
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'log4net,  Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its  dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.

[Here's where the Runtime version are.](https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html)

Any ideas on what I doing wrong?

tia

Comment: In visual studio, which CPU architecture are you targeting?  It usually defaults to "Any CPU", and if you did not change this, you will need to install both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of the runtime to avoid errors.  The version of the runtime needs to match the version of CR for Visual Studio, but I believe CR13 is the correct version for VS2010, so I would check the cpu architecture first.

Comment: @R. McMillan. Thanks for the reply. I have the Build|Platform Target set as "Any CPU". I shall set it to 32bit, re build any try again.